# How to match `an array of struct` with `arrays of signals`? (unpacked)

Tags: system-verilog

I have a module:

```
module test(
    inout logic [3:0] data [NUM],
    ...
    inout logic       anything [NUM]
);
```

by

```
struct {
  logic [3:0] data; // tri-states, can't use tri in struct
  ...
  logic       anything; 
} dut [NUM];

test test_i(
  .data     (dut.data), // should be same as [3:0] data [NUM]
  ...
  .anything (dut.anything)
);
```

I get: **Cannot select `data` in `dut` due to dimension mismatch.**

**Why?** What can I do to match my unpacked struct to the  modport?

There are a lot of signals, that's why I'd like to use `struct` instead of several logic array signals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a struct as a datatype for a wire, you just need a `typedef`

```
typedef struct {
  logic [3:0] data;
  ...
  logic       anything; 
} dut_t;
tri dut_t dut[NUM];
```

(See [this post](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/usage-var#reply-42240) for a more detailed explanation)

But the bigger problem is you cannot slice an array of a struct to get an array of struct members. You can only select an element of the array, and then select a member, i.e. `dut[0].data`

You would have to do

```
typedef struct {
  logic [3:0] data[NUM];
  ...
  logic       anything[NUM]; 
} dut_t;
tri dut_t dut;
```

Which probably defeats the purpose of what you wanted to do.

Comment: All my signals aren't tri-state. And yes I forgot that was one of the weak point of systemverilog... Thanks for the confirmation!